# What does "Q" mean?

Tags: plot-explanation, la-confidential

During the night scene in *L.A Confidential* (1997), Officer Bud White and Dick Stensland are stationed in a
car outside a residence, observing as a man inside physically assaults
his spouse:

> Dick Stensland: You're like Santa Claus with that list, Bud, except
> everyone on it's been naughty.
>
> Bud White: Guy's been out of **Q** two weeks.
>
> Dick Stensland: Leave it for later.

What does "Q" mean ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Likely he's referring to [San Quentin](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/San_Quentin_State_Prison), a well known prison near to Los Angeles.

> Some of the synonyms for San Quentin include "The Q," "SQ," "The Rock," and "The Big House."
>
> <sub><sup>https://www.thesaurus.net/san%20quentin</sup></sub>

Later in the film they refer to it as 'Quentin' (without the San)

> Bud White: You know what they do to kiddie rapers **in Quentin**, don't ya?

Comment: Isn't "The Rock" Alcatraz? And "the big house" can refer to any prison.

Comment: @Barmar yes to both. And SAN Quentin is near San Francisco, not Los Angeles.

Comment: @DaleM - Yes, but the film is, if memory serves, set in LA

Comment: In 1953, the [only men's state prison in Southern California](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_California_state_prisons) was the minimum-security [California Institution for Men](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Institution_for_Men), so it isn't surprising that more hardened LA criminals would have instead served time in Northern California's San Quentin.

Comment: Indeed, but the point is that San Quentin is ~400 miles (~650 km) away from Los Angeles, so saying the prison is "near to Los Angeles" is like saying Paris is "near" Munich.